How to prevent row selection when clicking an icon in a DT cell?
In this example app:
library(shiny)
library(DT)
li <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  Description = rep(li, 3)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
js <- JS(
  "function(data, type, row, meta) {
     if (type === 'display' && data.length > 40) {
       var truncated = data.substr(0, 38) + '...';
       var fullText = data;
       return '<span class=\"truncate\">' + truncated + '</span>' +
              '<span class=\"hidden-text\" style=\"display:none;\">' + fullText + '</span>' +
              '<span class=\"expand-icon\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onclick=\"' +
              'var icon = $(this); ' +
              'icon.prev().toggle(); ' +
              'icon.text(icon.text() === \\'▼\\' ? \\'▲\\' : \\'▼\\');' +
              '\">▼</span>'; 
     } else {
       return data;
     }
   }"
)
  
  output$mytable <- renderDT({
    datatable(data, escape = FALSE, options = list(columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = 2, render = js)
    )))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

How do I avoid selecting the row, when the icon for showing the original text of the cell is clicked?

You need to define the selection mode because you're using Shiny with DT. For example, add selection = "none" to the call for datatable(...). You can read more about this in section 2.1.1 here.

I don't want to disable row selection.

Alright, in that case, change your call to datatable(data, escape = FALSE, extensions = "Select", selection = "none", options = list(select = list(selector = "td :not(span.expand-icon)"), columnDefs = list(list(targets = 2, render = js)))) That should do what you're looking for. Want to know more? Check out section 13..

thanks, I tried, but, now, input$mytable_rows_selected fails (NULL when something selected on purpose), (using selection = "none"). If I remove it, the OP problem persists.

in the link, there is an icon workaround to select rows, but I don't consider it a proper solution to the OP, because it has that new "column". https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTcallbacks.html#change-row-css-properties-on-clicking-an-icon

Here's an update that addresses this no select issue you initially asked about, then clarified, then mentioned the issue with the use of input$mytable_rows_selected. (Hindsight being what it is...this information would have been fantastic in the original question! Alas, we're all humans here.)
To address the issue of selection except for the icon, you'll use the select extension, set selection to none and in options, you assign both:

items - what you want to select, so "row" (<- that's not in my code in my comment)
selector - what html elements you want to select (or not select, as it were)

Here's the call for the table (for use within Shiny)
output$mytable <- renderDT({           # use extensions Select
  datatable(selection = 'none', data, escape = FALSE, extensions = "Select",
            options = list(            # select rows, except for the icon
              rowID = 0, select = list(items = "row", selector = "td :not(span.expand-icon)"), 
              columnDefs = list(list(targets = 2, render = js)) # from question
            ))
}, server = F)                         # must declare non-server for the extension

Here's all of the code I used to render and test the outcome.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

li <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  Description = rep(li, 3)
)

ui <- fluidPage(     # modified to accommodate testing input$mytable...
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DTOutput("mytable")),
    column(5, offset=1,
           verbatimTextOutput('print'),
           DTOutput('info'))
  )   
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  js <- JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {
     if (type === 'display' && data.length > 40) {
       var truncated = data.substr(0, 38) + '...';
       var fullText = data;
       return '<span class=\"truncate\">' + truncated + '</span>' +
              '<span class=\"hidden-text\" style=\"display:none;\">' + fullText + '</span>' +
              '<span class=\"expand-icon\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onclick=\"' +
              'var icon = $(this); ' +
              'icon.prev().toggle(); ' +
              'icon.prev().prev().toggle(); ' +
              'icon.text(icon.text() === \\'▼\\' ? \\'▲\\' : \\'▼\\');' +
              '\">▼</span>'; 
     } else {
       return data;
     }
   }")

  output$mytable <- renderDT({           # use extensions Select
    datatable(selection = 'none', data, escape = FALSE, extensions = "Select",
              options = list(            # select rows, except for the icon
                rowID = 0, select = list(items = "row", selector = "td :not(span.expand-icon)"), 
                columnDefs = list(list(targets = 2, render = js)) # from question
              ))
  }, server = F) # must declare non-server for the extension

  # outputs added to accommodate testing input$mytable...
  output$print = renderPrint({    # show selected row index number
    print(input$mytable_rows_selected)
  }) 
    
  output$info = DT::renderDT({    # show selected rows in a new table
    index = input$mytable_rows_selected
    if (length(index)){ index2 = index[length(index)] }
    else{ index2 = index }
    data[index2, 1:2]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



Do you think it is possible with server TRUE?

As far as I know, the extension version only works with that set to false.

(As I understand it...) I should add that the DT library uses its own version of select to support Shiny (instead of the version that DataTable uses inherently). That being said, I assume the reason it doesn't work with server-side because it uses JQuery/Javascript, not R, so it doesn't need to use an R interpreter to function. All browsers can support JQuery/Javascript because that's what they're built on.

In this workaround, which handles server = TRUE,
clicking anywhere in the large text cells expands/contracts them,
while at the same time avoiding the selection of its row.
The difference with the original OP request is that there it was
requested to expand/contract only clicking in the triangles.
The relevance of this workaround relies in the possibility of using server = TRUE
Other approaches also have the limitation of losing the state of selected rows, when changing pages, when server = TRUE.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

li <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:12,
  Description = rep(li, 12)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("mytable"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  js <- JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
    "  if (type === 'display' && data.length > 40) {",
    "    var truncated = data.substr(0, 38) + '...';",
    "    var fullText = data;",
    "    return '<span class=\"truncate\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">' + truncated + '</span>' +",
    "           '<span class=\"hidden-text\" style=\"display:none; cursor:pointer;\">' + fullText + '</span>' +",
    "           '<span class=\"expand-icon\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">▼</span>';",
    "  } else {",
    "    return data;",
    "  }",
    "}"
  )

  output$mytable <- renderDT(
    {
      datatable(
        data,
        escape = FALSE,
        selection = list(mode = "multiple", target = "row"),
        options = list(
          columnDefs = list(
            list(targets = 2, render = js)
          ),
          rowCallback = JS(
            "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex, dataIndex) {",
            "  var $td = $('td', row).eq(2);",
            "  $td.css('cursor', 'pointer');",
            "  $td.off('mousedown').on('mousedown', function(e) {",
            "    e.stopPropagation();",
            "  });",
            "  $td.off('click').on('click', function(e) {",
            "    var icon = $td.find('.expand-icon');",
            "    var truncatedText = $td.find('.truncate');",
            "    var fullText = $td.find('.hidden-text');",
            "    truncatedText.toggle();",
            "    fullText.toggle();",
            "    icon.text(icon.text() === '▼' ? '▲' : '▼');",
            "  });",
            "}"
          ),
          scrollX = TRUE
        )
      )
    },
    server = TRUE
  )

  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    input$mytable_rows_selected
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


